# Up button not working after disable Drawer Indicator

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity, navigation-drawer

I am using this code to change the hamburger button to up button after certain method of my activity is called.

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This is my `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
else if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
            action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
            action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
```

However, when I tap the up button, nothing happened. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by moving the code to `setToolbarNavigationClickListener` instead.

```
mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
                action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
                action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Awesome! I have been searching for this solution about a week. I have even started to reimplement the whole `appBar Drawer` logic interaction in my app.